# How to use fsolve() with det()

Tags: matlab

I want to solve `det(A)=0` for a large matrix `A` with each element a function of `w`.

One way to solve these (simple) problems is using a symbolic approach, e.g.:

```
A = sym('[w, 1; 2, 4*w^2 + 2]');
answer = solve(det(A),'w');
```

However, I want solve a much larger problem where the equation of each element is defined as a function handle (e.g. `A4 = @(w) 4*w^2 + 2;`), and may need to be solved numerically with `fsolve()`.

The problem is that I cannot directly put the function handles in matrix `A` - they need to be put in a cell array, but then `solve(det(A))` is incompatible with cell arrays and returns `"Undefined function 'det' for input arguments of type 'cell'."`

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to following approach using you minimal example.

```
% Defining all functions as cells:
f{1,1} = @(w)w;
f{1,2} = @(w)1;
f{2,1} = @(w)2;
f{2,2} = @(w)4*w.^2+2;

% Function to solve
fsol = @(w)det(cellfun(@(x)x(w),f));

% Using fsolve
fsolve(fsol,0)
```

The result is

```
0.5898
```

which is equal to the (real) solution using symbolic math.